"not enough memory" error using multiprocessing
I have a table_data which is a type of list. It has 3.5 million sqlalchemy ORM-Models stored in it.
Now for each element in table_data list I want to preprocess some fields in these models and convert each one of them to the new sqlalchemy FooModel.
So basically I have this code:
#In this case, preprocess() function would get a list of table_data models and it would return list of FooModel models

table_data = extract_rows_from_database()
preprocessed_models = preprocess(table_data)

This code above works, but I was wondering if I could speed up this process using multiprocessing
# In this case preprocess() function would have one orm model as an argument, and it would return FooModel item

with ProcessPoolExecutor(process_workers) as exe:
        for result in exe.map(preprocess,table_data):
           preprocessed_models.append(result)

But when I use multiprocessing my container keeps exiting with code 137 (not enough memory) or
 concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

Entire function pseudocode would look like this
(inspired by this link) https://stackoverflow.com/a/20849064/17220672
def function(): 
   table_data = extract_rows_from_database()
   preprocessed_models = []
   with ProcessPoolExecutor(process_workers) as exe:
            for result in exe.map(preprocess,table_data):
               preprocessed_models.append(result)
   load_in_another_database(preprocessed_models)

**** load_in_another_database() uses sqlalchemy, I would like to parallelize this too!

It might be faster but what is actually slow right now?  Is the preprocess of a single object very complicated/time consuming?  Also how are you loading them into the new db?  Are you using sqlalchemy for that as well?

Sorry about that, just edited my question. Preprocessing does not work, container exits with these two errors mentioned above. When Im using synchronous execution, my code runs well, but its slow. I just dont understand what am I doing wrong with multiprocessing. Should I use threading instead?

The pseudocode is missing a lot of information that would determine the best way to solve this, ie. threads, processes, or neither.  Passing a single model to each process is going to be slower than just not using a pool at all unless pre-processing a single model takes tens of seconds itself.


Can you break up the source data into chunks and preprocess them independently?  2. Does the order of the models being preprocessed matter?  3. Does the order of the processed models being written out to the second db matter?


*1. Yes, I can use 'stream_results' for fetching data from db (isnt it better to have one big query instead of few small ones?). *2. Order does not matter at all. *3. Order written to db also does not matter. If you have a proposal on how should I approach this problem please tell, and also, I dont get why multiprocessing is so slow. Is it because before invoking ProcessPoolExecutor() there is 'table_data' variable in RAM which is 3.5gb large, so this memory also gets copied to child processes ? Its a linux image,so am guessing there is CoW implemented.That should not be a problem I guess?

What if you reduced their count from 4 million to 40 thousand and dropped the rest, does the app work fine ? If yes then you are running out of memory consistently, in which case you need to stream the data, just read them in chunks of 40k then pass them to workers then repeat, also with how little code you have posted it is impossible to know if this is just wrong architecturally or you have a bug somewhere else in your code, which is highly likely.

Ok, with a lot of digging I have found an answer. There are two problems.

My preprocess() function does just one simple operation on one field. (etc. formats a string). This is not a cpu intensive task, so the function I am trying to parallelize does not require enough CPU resources for interpreter to rationalise parallelization .
.map() function is not well suited for huge chunks of data. There is a problem of inter-process communication. Basically when a parent process delegates to child processes, that delegation consists of constantly switching partitions of the list to other child processes. Also there is a problem how map handles this data. It initializes 3 queues (taskqueue, inqueue, outqueue). First queue basically stores our function (preprocess()) and chunk of data from iterable. inqueue holds serialized (pickled) tasks, outqueue holds serialized results. When pool of workers are created, they consume these queues, first worker removes task from inqueue, deserialises them, executes the task, serialises the result and sends it to outqueue. Basically there is a whole lot of serialization for each element of data. This blows up our memory.

Reference: map serialisation problem

This example passes batches of ids into the worker processes.  The worker processes preprocess those rows from that model and then write out the results to another model.  There might be faster ways but this should get you started and not go too far overboard on memory.  You could try subbing it out with threading.  There are other tricks to make this better but it gets kind of confusing.
import os
from itertools import islice
import math
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime


from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Boolean,
    ForeignKey,
    create_engine
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import (
    func,
    select,
    insert,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    declarative_base,
    Session,
    relationship,
    joinedload,
)


MAX_OVERFLOW = 20


POOL_SIZE = 10


def get_engine(env):
    return create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}", pool_size=POOL_SIZE, max_overflow=MAX_OVERFLOW)

Base = declarative_base()

class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'samples'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class Result(Base):
    __tablename__= 'results'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sample_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('samples.id'))
    is_prime = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    sample = relationship('Sample')


def preprocess_pass_ids(batch_of_ids):
    """ Process the given ids. """
    print (f'Starting preprocess of ids set starting with id: {batch_of_ids[0]} in pid: {os.getpid()}.')
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)
    batch_q = select(Sample).order_by(Sample.id).where(Sample.id.in_(batch_of_ids))
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        with Session(conn) as db_session:
            results = [{
                'sample_id': sample.id,
                'is_prime': is_prime(sample.value),
            } for sample in db_session.scalars(batch_q)]
            write_results(db_session, results)
            db_session.commit()


def write_results(db_session, results, batch_count=10_000):
    # Write in batches so we don't overload query size.
    for results_batch in batched(results, batch_count):
        stmt = insert(Result).values(results_batch)
        db_session.execute(stmt)


def generate_results(engine):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            q = select(Sample.id).order_by(Sample.id)
            # Just split the ids into groups and pass each group to a worker.
            with Session(conn) as db_session:
                start = datetime.now()
                for res in executor.map(preprocess_pass_ids, (batch_of_ids for batch_of_ids in db_session.scalars(q, execution_options={'yield_per': 50_000}).partitions())):
                    print ((res,))
                print (f'Done in {datetime.now() - start}')


def main():

    engine = get_engine(os.environ)

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        Base.metadata.create_all(conn)
        conn.commit()

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        populate(conn)

    generate_results(engine)

    count = check_results(engine)

    engine.dispose()
    return count


def check_results(engine):
    """ Check the count of results and then print the first few. """
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        q = select(func.count(Result.id))
        count = conn.scalar(q)
        q = select(Result).join(Result.sample).options(joinedload(Result.sample)).order_by(Sample.value).limit(30)
        with Session(conn) as db_session:
            for result in db_session.scalars(q):
                print (f"(value, is_prime) = ({result.sample.value}, {result.is_prime})")
    return count


def populate(conn):
    """ Create a bunch of test data if the database is empty. """
    res = conn.scalar(select(func.count(Sample.__table__.c.id)))
    if res > 0:
        return
    sample_count = 1_000_000
    # Write in batches so we don't overload query size.
    batch_count = 10_000
    sample_value_sets = batched(range(1, sample_count), batch_count)
    for sample_values in sample_value_sets:
        rows = []
        for value in sample_values:
            rows.append(dict(value=value))
        conn.execute(insert(Sample.__table__).values(rows))
        conn.commit()


def is_prime(n):
    """ Simple is_prime taken straight from Python doc concurrent.futures example. """
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


# I don't have python 3.12.
def batched(iterable, n):
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield batch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (main())

Some other tricks:

Only pass in the first id of a batch to the task processes from the dispatcher and let the task process select to get the first id and the next 50,000 of that batch using something like WHERE id >= batch_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 50000.  Might have to work around some duplicates if the result set is actively changing.
Create a partition of the id set (if it is integers that are continuous) using a prime number and its remainders, ie. id % prime == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.  Then pass the remainder to each task processes and let it gather the records by performing that computation.
Any other way you could partition the data set evenly to pass subsets to the task processes, ie. using ranges of datetimes, etc.  Using the first character of a UUID or whatever evenly distributes the batches.


Thank you for a detailed response, but 'executor.map(preprocess_pass_ids, (batch_of_ids for batch_of_ids in db_session.scalars(q, execution_options={'yield_per': 50_000}).partitions())):' This is again big chunk of data being sent to map, and with constant pickling I am expecting this to be slow. Am I missing something ?

This was just the easiest but still functional solution I could write up without knowing anything about the dataset or what the actual computation was.  I added some more tricks.  There are a lot of ways to approach this depending on that information.  There is threads, asyncio and processes.  Or even a combination of processes and threads.  You'll have to benchmark them starting with an optimized single threads probably.  Also if you are just formatting a string maybe you could have the database do that itself and stream the results right into the other database...?

Right now I am asynchronously yielding chunks of data from source db. These chunks are inserted to asyincio.Queue.Also asynchronously,  I am fetching data from queue, and inserting processed data into another database. Now I am interested If I can speed loading with combining multiprocessing/threading and asyncio ? Maybe creating pool of workers and they get their chunk of data which is sent to a database. Does this make any sense to you ? Also I will try your approach with formatting string
